# I can´t install Microsoft Office 2010

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I re installed Ubuntu many times and I still can't get it working.

I get this:

```
Error in POL_Wine
Wine seems to have crashed

If your program is running, just ignore this message
```

And then I press <kbd>Next</kbd> I get this:

```
Error in POL_Shortcut
Binary not found: WINWORD.EXE
Have you installed the program to the default location?
```

And then this:

```
Error in POL_Shortcut
Binary not found: EXCEL.EXE
Have you installed the program to the default location?
```

then this:

```
Error in POL_Shortcut
Binary not found: POWERPNT.EXE
Have you installed the program to the default location?
```

then this:

```
Error in POL_Shortcut
Binary not found: ONENOTE.EXE
Have you installed the program to the default location?
```

etc.

I have BumbleBee installed using a gt555M. And the MS Word is a 32 bit version and I already tried other MS Word installations. I installed a game called SuperMeatBoy using PlayOnLinux and that works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The best option I have found is to install PlayOnLinux.

PlayOnLinux uses the wine technology but will also install extra libraries specific to certain programs. The last I checked, it supported Office 2010. I have it running with Excel, Word, OneNote, Sharepoint and Powerpoint.

[image: Office running on PlayOnLinux]

Comment: `Error in POL_Wine` suggests, he is already using PlayOnLinux

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem too with it while using PlayOnLinux. And I was doing seriously stupid mistake. Be sure you don't do it. First of all get a x86 copy, secondly you have to mount and iso using mount command or program like Furius ISO Mount and then in PlayOnLinux choose the setup.exe. I thought that POL will automatically mount image for me but it doesn't. So choose the setup.exe in POL not an iso file.

Comment: In my case, the setup files were compressed into a 7zip and password-protected. So it couldn't be read. Once I extracted them and ran the setup.exe like erbepl stated, it worked.